# Why only one parent object is created in case of Serialization/Deserialization

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

Why only one parent object is created in case of Serialization/Deserialization

```
//superclass A 
//A class doesn't implement Serializable
//interface.
class A 
{
    int i;

    // parameterized constructor
    public A(int i)
    {
        this.i = i;
    }

    // default constructor
    public A()
    {
        i = 50;
        System.out.println("A's class constructor called");
    }
}

// subclass B implementing Serializable interface
class B extends A implements Serializable
{
    int j;

    public B(int i, int j)
    {
        super(i);
        System.out.println("B.B()");
        this.j = j;
    }
}

// Driver class
public class SerializationWithInheritanceExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        B b1 = new B(10, 20);

        System.out.println("i = " + b1.i);
        System.out.println("j = " + b1.j);

        // Serializing B's(subclass) object
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("abc.ser");
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos))
        {
            // Method for serialization of B's class object
            oos.writeObject(b1);
        }

        System.out.println("Object has been serialized\n");

        // Reading the object from a file
        readObject();
        readObject();
        readObject();

    }

    static void readObject()
    {
        // Reading the object from a file
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("abc.ser"); ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis))
        {
            // Method for de-serialization of B's class object
            B b2 = (B) ois.readObject();

            System.out.println("HasCode of A:"+ b2.getClass().getSuperclass().hashCode() +" | HasCode of B:"+b2.hashCode());

            System.out.println("i = " + b2.i);
            System.out.println("j = " + b2.j);
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
B.B()
i = 10
j = 20
Object has been serialized

A's class constructor called
HasCode of A:1311053135 | HasCode of B:1705736037
i = 50
j = 20
A's class constructor called
HasCode of A:1311053135 | HasCode of B:455659002
i = 50
j = 20
A's class constructor called
HasCode of A:1311053135 | HasCode of B:250421012
i = 50
j = 20
```

While de-serialization of B's object multiple time only one object of class A parent is created. 
Why only one object is created ?

Comment: Why do you say that 'only one object of class A parent' is created?  -- Is it because the HashCode of A that is being printed out?  If yes, recheck the code..  That is the hashcode of the class, not of the object.  The JVM will only ever load one instance of an objects class into memory per class loader.   You should go by the hash code of B as evidence that A is being loaded each time.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisK for your explanation.

Comment: 'Only one object of class A parent is created' is obviously false. The traces indicate that three are created. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP Yes my understanding was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the `hashCode()` method of an instance of `A`, but of the class `A`, there is - in most situations - only one instance of the class object.

Lets break it down:

```
b2               // instance of B
.getClass()      // Class<B>
.getSuperclass() // Class<A>
.hashCode()      // hash code of Class<A>
```

It is not even possible to get a separate hash code for the 'parts of `A`' of an instance of `B`: there is only one object, and it has only one hash code.

When you create a `B`, only one object is created, not two like you seem to think. This object contains all of `B`, which includes the parts of `A`.

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining more about why only one object is created for B.   The following link explains the JVMs memory layout for objects that extend each other.  The key take away is that in memory B is represented by the concatenation of B and A within a single sequence of memory.   http://www.programcreek.com/2011/11/what-do-java-objects-look-like-in-memory/

Answer (score 1):

When you call `b2.getClass().getSuperclass()` you have an instance of type `Class<A>`. This is only object for class A, which has information about declaration of class `A`. When you call `b2.hashCode()` you have hash code of instance, which referred to `b2`.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of A you get hashcode of a **class** A. In the case of B you get hashcode of **instance** B. And your 3 instances of B are sharing 1 superclass A (along with class B). So, for example, if you call `b2.getClass().hashcode()` 3 times the output will be equal for all these method invocation too, because you have 1 class B.